# What is the difference between "$form->..." and "$this->Form->..." in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, syntax

This seems simple and I think I know the answer but I've searched and can't find anything to back up my assumption.

Many CakePHP code samples use the following syntax:

```
echo $form->inputs();
```

When I write Cake views using 1.3 or 2.0-RC1, the above syntax does not work but the following does:

```
echo $this->Form->inputs();
```

Is `$form` simply a deprecated syntax from an old version?  Or is it a community-accepted shorthand for abbreviating the longer `$this->Form` version?  (Or something else?)

Comment: I did not tag this question with "PHP" tag because it is specifically about CakePHP syntax which really isn't a general PHP issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that myself before. By taking a look into the CakePHP-books for versions 1.2 and 1.3 it turns out, that they use $form up to version 1.2 and $this->Form since version 1.3. So $form seems to be deprecated now.

Version 1.2: http://book.cakephp.org/view/183/Creating-Forms
Version 1.3: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1384/Creating-Forms

EDIT:
For further explanation see: [Cakephp Helpers in Views and $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106953/cakephp-helpers-in-views-and-this)

Comment: Thanks for the above and had noticed as much myself. Curious if there was ever an official Cake announcement about the changed syntax.  +1 for the link to the other Q that I didn't find when I searched.

Comment: At least there is a changelog entry: "Updating default views and baking templates to use $this->Helper syntax for helpers." (http://cakephp.org/changelogs/1.3.0-beta, commit cf42c8d)

Answer (score 1):

$form is deprecated syntax for 1.3. It's used in cakephp 1.2

If you are using cakephp version 1.2, you'll need $form.
Otherwise, when you are using cakephp 1.3 you'll need $this->Form